# linux: directory created with Access: (0000/d---------)

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

On a Linux (ubuntu) machine, an automated script running as a normal user is creating a subdirectory under its home directory. For some reason, the directory is created with `Access: (0000/d---------)`. umask is 0022. This obviously means the script can't create any files in that directory.
Can anyone think of anything?

**Apparently this only happens with the non-superuser account.**

***Update:*** The problem was actually a bug. mkdir was called as a system command from C code, not as the command-line utility. And the programmer who called it used mode=0...

Anyway - the reason it DID work when running as root, is that root can create files in directories even when the permissions don't allow it.

Comment: wow, cool problem. Thanks for updating with the solution

Answer (score 1):

What is the umask of that users login session set to?

Also you can always chmod the directory after you create it. "man chmod" for details.